# Pine Script - plot horizontal line at the high of a particular time range of any previous session irrespective of my current session

Tags: pine-script

I need help in getting the high of a past time range. The time range is selected through datetime picker.

The code below gives option to select a start time and end time. After the time range is selected, it highlights the background for this time range on chart. What I can't code is to get the high of this highlighted time range.

```
//@version=4
study("Price Channel with date range", overlay=true)

i_startTime = input(defval = timestamp("23 Apr 2021 04:45 +0000"), title = "Start Time", type = input.time)
i_endTime = input(defval = timestamp("23 Apr 2021 05:00 +0000"), title = "End Time", type = input.time)

inDateRange = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime
bgcolor(inDateRange ? color.lime : na, 50)

// To DO -- Get the high of this time range
// the time difference here is 15 minute, I need the high of this 15 minute time frame plotted automatically when I select the start time and end time
// I have drawn a line at the high of this time range manually
```

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afternoon,
I updated my Trading View Time frame (bottom right corner) to reflect the Symbol info (+5:30).

[image]

```
 //@version=4

study("Trading View", overlay=true)

// User adjustment inputs
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=20)


// Asia Start
time_int_01 = input("1015-1030:1234567", "Time", input.session)

in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)

plot(not in_time_int_01 ? highe_01 : na, title="High", color=color.purple, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_01 ? highe_01 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="High")
```

###########Updated Answer##############

You can pick and choose what days you would like to see in the setting.

[image]

```
//@version=4

study("Trading View", overlay=true)

// User adjustment inputs
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=20)

// Monday High
time_int_02 = input("1015-1030:2", "Monday", input.session)

in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)

var highe_02 = 0.0
var lowe_02  = 10e10
if in_time_int_02
    if not in_time_int_02[1]
        highe_02 := high
    else
        highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)

plot(not in_time_int_02 ? highe_02 : na, title="Monday High", color=color.purple, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_02 ? highe_02 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Monday High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Monday High")

// Tuesday High
time_int_03 = input("1015-1030:3", "Tuesday", input.session)

in_time_int_03 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_03)

var highe_03 = 0.0
var lowe_03  = 10e10
if in_time_int_03
    if not in_time_int_03[1]
        highe_03 := high
    else
        highe_03 := max(high, highe_03)

plot(not in_time_int_03 ? highe_03 : na, title="Tuesday High", color=color.blue, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_03 ? highe_03 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Tuesday High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Tuesday High")

// Wednesday High
time_int_04 = input("1015-1030:4", "Wednesday", input.session)

in_time_int_04 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_04)

var highe_04 = 0.0
var lowe_04  = 10e10
if in_time_int_04
    if not in_time_int_04[1]
        highe_04 := high
    else
        highe_04 := max(high, highe_04)

plot(not in_time_int_04 ? highe_04 : na, title="Wednesday High", color=color.orange, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_04 ? highe_04 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.orange,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Wednesday High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Wednesday High")

// Thursday High
time_int_05 = input("1015-1030:5", "Thursday", input.session)

in_time_int_05 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_05)

var highe_05 = 0.0
var lowe_05  = 10e10
if in_time_int_05
    if not in_time_int_05[1]
        highe_05 := high
    else
        highe_05 := max(high, highe_05)

plot(not in_time_int_05 ? highe_05 : na, title="Thursday High", color=color.green, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_05 ? highe_05 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.green,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Thursday High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Thursday High")

// Friday High
time_int_06 = input("1015-1030:6", "Friday", input.session)

in_time_int_06 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_06)

var highe_06 = 0.0
var lowe_06  = 10e10
if in_time_int_06
    if not in_time_int_06[1]
        highe_06 := high
    else
        highe_06 := max(high, highe_06)

plot(not in_time_int_06 ? highe_06 : na, title="Friday High", color=color.white, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_06 ? highe_06 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.white,  textcolor=color.black, show_last=1, text="Friday High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Friday High")
```

To hard code as per your comment question:

Current code:

```
time_int_02 = input("1015-1030:2", "Monday", input.session)
in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)
```

Delete first line and move the time to second line:

```
in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, "1015-1030:2")
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. Sorry I did not include the code. I have added the code in my question.

Comment: Evening,
Could you upload a picture with symbol and manually draw the lines on. So I can get a better picture/understanding of your question. Cheers

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture and other details. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Is it just for that date of the same time period every day?

Comment: Do you update your Trading View UTC time to the same as the Symbol Time (Symbol Time is +5:30 Kolkata)?

I have also updated my answer.

Comment: No, it is not just for that same time every day, it can be any time period which I select from the date picker.

And yes I updated my Trading View time to the Symbol time.

Comment: Have you tried the updated script and looked at the picture in my answer above? I believe it is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I just added your updated script and it is working for me, Really appreciate your help.. Is it possible for your script not to plot the line for a live session ? Lines plotted for past session(s) is my requirement. I want today's line to be plotted after today's session is closed.

Comment: How to hard code the session time, instead of user input if required ? For e.g. Hard code 10:15:10:30

time_int_02 = input("1015-1030:2", "Monday", input.session)

Comment: I have added the answer to your question ref hard code to my answer above (at the bottom). If you are happy give the question a tick as answered cheers.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have given the tick, but my vote will not be counted unless I have a reputation of 15. Currently it is 11 for me.