# Session highs and lows pivots cut through candles

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I came across this post : [Pine Script - plot horizontal line at the high of a particular time range of any previous session irrespective of my current session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67228523/pine-script-plot-horizontal-line-at-the-high-of-a-particular-time-range-of-any)

It does something i am looking for, it cuts through candles. Now i want the session highs and lows of the most recent session.

So i started to see if i can do this (with chatGPT) to show me just the most recent Asian Session high. If i get that, i can work from the for the lows and other session.

I have gotten close but the high isn't exact and for some reason, it keeps drawing multiple sessions instead of just the last one. It seems to ignore `show last 1`

```
study("Sessions high and lows", overlay=true)

// User adjustment inputs
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=10)

// Asian High
time_int_02 = input("2000-2359", "Assian High", input.session)

in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)

var highe_02 = 0.0
var lowe_02  = 10e10
if in_time_int_02
    if not in_time_int_02[1]
        highe_02 := high
    else
        highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)

plot(not in_time_int_02 ? highe_02 : na, title="Asian High", color=color.purple, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_02 ? highe_02 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asian High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asian High")
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? If someone can help me out with this, i can build on from there.

Thanks you kindly

Comment: you use show_last only for plotshape and get only one last plothape, it's work properly
So u want to show high from last session from 20:00 to 23:59, but not to show last value during this session time, correct? Or just show high from previous session, and show it for current session time?
+ you don't use timezone for time func, so time 20:00 to 23:59 using time zone from default exchange timezone from current chart symbol

Comment: I want to show the high from (most recent) Asian session, and draw it up until current time. Important is that it cuts through the candles. Lets say that high has been taken, i still want the line to reach current time.

My chart is always on GMT-5 NY Time